# How to make the radial part of elements with border-radius applied to them, unselectable in chrome and safari?

Tags: css

In this circle, I noticed the pointer only appears when the cursor is inside the circle for IE9 and firefox.  However in safari or chrome the cursor is a pointer if you are anywhere inside the `div` element, even if you are outside of the circle.

```
div#circle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   -moz-border-radius:100px;
   -webkit-border-radius:100px;
   border-radius:100px;
   background: red;
   cursor:pointer }

<div id = "circle"></div>
```

Look at this fiddle in IE9 and Firefox and compare to Safari and Chrome.
http://jsfiddle.net/GC4yU/

Is there any way make this code function the same way it does in ie9 and firefox in chrome and safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is probably due to the way the HTML engine works. I don't know what causes that. But you can consider the following alternatives:

- You can use an `<img>` tag and use a image map. Its is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp. Demo [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap).
- You can use the [raphaelJS library](http://raphaeljs.com/) to generate SVG. Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.
- You can also draw SVG yourself. [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUkPV/).

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
       <circle style="cursor:pointer" cx="100" cy="50" r="40" 
               stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```